# SQL: How to join correctly in order to calculate contact statistics from call log

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The call log has the following columns:

```
CallingParty, CalledParty, Duration, EventTime
```

and the example data is the following:

```
X, a, 10, 10:20
X, b, 12, 10:34
X, c, 8, 12:08
a, X, 22, 12:45
X, a, 10, 13:55
d, X, 30, 15:01
```

What I would like to do is to calculate the statistics for each contact (how many times did the user X call the contact, what was the sum of outgoing calls duration, how many times did the contact call user X, and what was the sum of incoming calls duration). Actually I am trying to mine the data from the call log of user X.

The statistics for the example above would be the following:

```
contactName, incomingCallsCount, IncomingCallsDuration, OutgoingCallsCount, OutgoingCallsDuration
a, 1, 10, 2, 20
b, 0, 0, 1, 12
c, 0, 0, 1, 8
d, 1, 30, 0, 0
```

I tryed the following query with different joins () but couldn't fet the right result

```
    SELECT t1.CallingParty AS Contact, t1.CallingPartyCount, t1.CallingPartyDuration, t2.CalledPartyCount, t2.CalledPartyDuration FROM
(SELECT e.CallingParty, COUNT(*) AS CallingPartyCount, SUM(CAST(REPLACE(e.Duration, 'NULL', '0') AS int)) AS CallingPartyDuration FROM Events e WHERE Duration <> 'NULL' GROUP BY e.CallingParty) t1
<JOIN>
(SELECT e.CalledParty, COUNT(*) AS CalledPartyCount, SUM(CAST(REPLACE(e.Duration, 'NULL', '0') AS int)) AS CalledPartyDuration FROM Events e WHERE Duration <> 'NULL' GROUP BY e.calledParty) t2
ON t1.CallingParty = t2.CalledParty
```

Does anyone know what would be the right query in order to get the correct statistics?

Thank You!

Comment: do you have another table with all the contacts, whether they have events or not?

Comment: Why would you need a join? Each 'statistic' can just be derived from the table with the appropriate where-clause, so all you need are IF's to count or UNION's to merge the results?

Comment: @Bohemian: yes, I have another table with contacts

Comment: Negative @Konerak - you do need joins - what if they havent made any calls, but have received them - without joins u get nuthin

Comment: @Bohemian: false. Counterexample: imagine 'c' has not made any calls, but received a call from someone: `select duration from Events where calledparty = 'c'` would find where c has been called?

Comment: Shouldn't the output for `a` be *'a, 1, **22**, 2, 20'*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be joining to begin with, it sounds more like a simple group by with sum and count.

```
SELECT CallingParty, CalledParty, SUM(Duration), COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY CallingParty, CalledParty
```

Now, you also need a set of all the users involved (a,b,c and d), that can be computed by using a UNION if you don't have this somewhere else.

```
SELECT CallingParty FROM table
UNION
SELECT CalledParty FROM table
```

Then you just put these together using CTEs.

```
WITH outgoing AS (
    SELECT CallingParty, CalledParty, SUM(Duration), COUNT(*)
    FROM table
    GROUP BY CallingParty, CalledParty
), incoming AS (
    SELECT CalledParty, CallingParty, SUM(Duration), COUNT(*)
    FROM table
    GROUP BY CalledParty, CallingParty
), users AS (
   SELECT CallingParty AS UserID FROM table
   UNION
   SELECT CalledParty AS UserID FROM table
)
SELECT * 
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN outgoing ON outgoing.CallingParty = UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN incoming ON incoming.CalledParty = UserID
```

That's should do it!

Comment: Way too complicated. See my solution for something A LOT simpler. I think you have over-thought it.

Comment: @Bohemian - Actually I've structued the problem into three seperate queries and then pulled those together, clearly showing what is being done where and why. If I ever need to change any piece of this query it's quite easy to do so while your answer is more compact it's not necessarily a lot simpler to adapt to the final result.

Comment: I guess I'll just return the favour.

Comment: Karma :) Now correct 'incomming' to 'incoming' and we're good ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer John. I guess there is an error in this query as it returns a message: The column 'CalledParty' was specified multiple times for 'incomming'

Comment: Typo. Change 1 calledparty to callingparty :)

Comment: Yes, I accidently used the same column name when I intended to just swap thier positions. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
WITH qry AS
(
    SELECT a.*,
          CASE CallingParty
            WHEN 'X' THEN CalledParty
            ELSE  CallingParty
          END AS contactName
        FROM CallLog a
     WHERE ( CallingParty = 'X' OR  CalledParty = 'X')
)
SELECT  contactName,
        SUM( CASE CallingParty WHEN 'X' 1 ELSE 0 END) AS incomingCallsCount,
        SUM( CASE CallingParty WHEN 'X' Duration ELSE 0 END) AS incomingDurationCount
        SUM( CASE CallingParty WHEN 'X' 0 ELSE 1 END) AS outgoingCallsCount,
        SUM( CASE CallingParty WHEN 'X' 0 ELSE Duration END) AS outgoingDurationCount
  FROM  qry
GROUP BY contactName
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot simpler than that:

```
SELECT contact, 
sum(t1.CallingParty is not null) as CallingPartyCount, 
sum(t1.CallingPartyDuration) as CallingPartyDuration, 
sum(t2.CalledPartyCount is not null) as CalledPartyCount, 
sum(t2.CalledPartyDuration) as CalledPartyDuration
FROM
(select distinct CallingParty as contact from Event) e
left join Event t1 on t1.CallingParty = contact
left join Event t2 on t2.CalledParty = contact
```

Comment: You know, this isn't even valid T-SQL. You can't put a predicate in a SQL Server aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it like this:

```
WITH EventsForX AS (
  SELECT
    isIncoming  = CASE CalledParty WHEN @X THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    contactName = CASE CalledParty WHEN @X THEN CallingParty ELSE CalledParty END,
    Duration,
  FROM Events
  WHERE CallingParty = @X
     OR CalledParty = @X
)
SELECT
  contactName,
  incomingCallsCount     = SUM(isIncoming),
  incomingCallsDuration  = SUM(isIncoming * Duration),
  outcomingCallsCount    = SUM(1 - isIncoming),
  outcomingCallsDuration = SUM((1 - isIncoming) * Duration)
FROM EventsForX
GROUP BY contactName
```